# Is it possible to configure Solr so that the cardinalities in queryResponse.getFacetFields() reflect a query in conjunctive normal form?

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet, conjunctive-normal-form

The Apache Solr API for faceted searching is very intutive. With SolrQuery class it is easy to build AND-concatenated queries, execute theme against the repository and process results. As very nice feature Solr sends back a queryResponse object with a FacetField list providing adapted cardinalities of remaining facets.

```java
for ( FacetField facetField : queryResponse.getFacetFields() )
{
    logger.debug( facetField.getName() );
    for ( Count count : facetField.getValues() )
    {
        logger.debug( " " + count.getName() + "(" + count.getCount() + ")" );
    }
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to configure Solr in a way that these returned cardinalities reflect queries in conjunctive normal formal (CNF), in other words queries of AND-concatenations of different facet fields and OR-concatenations of same facet fields?

At least in default configuration it seems that in `queryResponse.getFacetFields()` only AND-concatenated queries are supposed. I´d like to use `queryResponse.getFacetFields()` without workaround and have the hope that the issue is a matter of configuration.

For better understanding here a concrete use case with real and expected return values of the Solr API: A set of 1000 items is supposed. Each item may have several assignments of concepts and mode of collections. So the solr schema for an item document has the two fields `c` for concept and `moc` for mode of collection. Faceted search is enabled for these fields.

Hopefully easy to understand, here the relevant queries in pseudo code and cardinalities of the resulting sets. `F(c:position)` means the set of items which have the concept position assigned, `F(moc:postal)` means the set of items which have the mode of collection postal assigned. `Qi` shows the query and the resulting set, `|Qi|` is its cardinality.

```
Q1: F(c:position) 
    -> |Q1| = 252
Q2: F(moc:telefonic) 
    -> |Q2| = 393
Q3: F(moc:postal) 
    -> |Q3| = 464
Q4: F(c:position) AND F(moc:telefonic) 
    -> |Q4| = 14 + 10 = 24
Q5: F(c:position) AND F(moc:postal) 
    -> |Q5| = 33 + 10 = 43
Q6: F(c:position) AND F(moc:telefonic) AND F(moc:postal) 
    -> |Q6| = 10
Q7: F(c:position) AND F(moc:telefonic) AND NOT F(moc:postal) 
    -> |Q7| = 14
Q8: F(c:position) AND F(moc:postal) AND NOT F(moc:telefonic) 
    -> |Q8| = 33
Q9: F(c:position) AND (F(moc:telefonic) OR F(moc:postal)) 
    -> |Q9| = 14 + 10 + 33 = 57
```

Following figure shows the cardinalities of sets and subsets:

[image: Venn diagram for faceted search]

Now we start a specific search: Q9 is the query of interest. Any facets are selected. The facets show the expected values: 252 for Q1, 393 for Q2 and 464 for Q3. The user selects the facet `c:position` and reduces the cardinality of the result set from 1000 to 252. The underlying query is Q1. The returned facets show 24 items for `moc:telefonic` and 43 items for `moc:postal`. These values indicate that a selection of one of these facets would limit the result set to 24 (= 14 + 10) or to 43 (= 33 + 10) items. With the second step the user additionally chooses the facet `moc:postal`. The underlying query is Q5. Real and expected cardinality of the result set correspond to each other, it is 43. So far so good!

What cardinality of the facet `moc:telefonic` do you now expect to be returned given a CNF-query with the former selection? I expect 14 items. If I choose the facet `moc:telefonic` my result set would grow about these additional items from 43 to 57. Unfourtunately Solr shows 10 items. This would be correct if all facets are AND-concatenated. As user I get confused because my result set has 57 instead of 53 items.

```java
// Q5: F(c:position) AND F(moc:postal) 
solrDocumentList = queryResponse.getResults();
assertEquals( 43, solrDocumentList.getNumFound() );
facetField = queryResponse.getFacetField( "moc" );
assertEquals( "telefonic", facetField.getValues().get( 0 ).getName() );

// test fails: returned value is 10
assertEquals( 14, facetField.getValues().get( 0 ).getCount() );
```